# Priority Queue with ArrayList Parameters

Tags: java, arraylist, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a Priority Queue of two ArrayLists in Java. I want each in the queue to return (String, Integer) and I have an ArrayList of Strings and a separate ArrayList of Integers.

I know I can make two separate Priority Queues, but I want to make one that will take both parameters. Is this possible?

Comment: does each item in the priorityqueue need to have a string property and an integer property?

Comment: @mettleap yes, I was trying to have each string tied to a number ranking in the priority queue

Comment: Ohk, then why don't you just create a class which holds your string value and integer value and build a priorityqueue on that? That will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Can I still make a priority queue from those two arraylists? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Say you have list1 = {"A", "B", "C"} and list2 = {1, 2, 3}. So "A" is tied to 1, "B" is tied to 2 and so on, right? So, just define a class MyClass{ String str; Integer i} and create the MyClass objects by traversing the two arrayLists. Then create a PriorityQueue where each item will be of type MyClass.